# JSON serialization Value Conversion not tracking changes with EF Core

Tags: json, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I am using an EF Core value conversion.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions

I wrote a JSON serializer converter as follows:

```
private static ValueConverter<T, String> JsonValueConverter<T>()
{
    ValueConverter<T, String> jsonConverter = new ValueConverter<T, String>(
        v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v),
        v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(v));
    return jsonConverter;
}
```

Implemented in the app with:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder mb)
{    
   ...
   mb.Entity<MyObject>()
     .Property(p => p.MySerializableObject)
     .HasConversion(JsonValueConverter<MySerializableObject>());
   ...
}
```

It works.

However, when you make changes to a property inside the serialized object, EF Core change tracking does not pick up changes to `MySerializableObject`.

I assume there is some way to force this on the object level. I have attempted to implement `IEqualityComparer` on `MySerializableObject` but change tracking didn't start working.

Comment: `IEqualityComparer<T>` is for comparing objects other than the class implementing the interface. Your `MySerializableObject` should implement `IEquatable<MySerializableObject>` or just override `Equals` method (and of course in both cases override `GetHashCode`).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I was able to get change tracking to kick in by adding a `ValueConverter` and a `ValueComparer` to the Metadata of the property, however, my comparer is probably very inefficient. If anyone has suggestions on performance tuning for this, it would be much appreciated.

```
mb.Entity<MyObject>().Property(p => .MySerializableObject).HasJsonConversion();
```

With the new HasJsonConversion extension method

```
public static class ValueConversionExtensions
{
    public static PropertyBuilder<T> HasJsonConversion<T>(this PropertyBuilder<T> propertyBuilder)
    {           
        ValueConverter<T, String> converter = new ValueConverter<T, String>(
            v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v),
            v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(v));

        ValueComparer<T> comparer = new ValueComparer<T>(
            (l, r) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(l) == JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r),
            v => v == null ? 0 : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v).GetHashCode(),
            v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v)));

        propertyBuilder.HasConversion(converter);
        propertyBuilder.Metadata.SetValueConverter(converter);
        propertyBuilder.Metadata.SetValueComparer(comparer);            

        return propertyBuilder;
    }        
}
```

Comment: This ain't working for me unfortunately. I've this in a .NETStandard library. Could that be a reason? Also I'm using System.Text.Json instead of Newtonsoft. When the string data is retrieved from the database it's not deserialized as expected. So the object exists but all properties on it are null or default values.

Comment: This should work work STJ, but you'll need to modify the syntax because it's slightly different that json.net. This code is just a hook into the conversion of data.